# read_to_end method never returns for UnixStream

Tags: rust, unix-socket

I'm working in an application that uses Unix domain sockets to communicate processes. For this purpose, I'm using the `UnixListener` and `UnixStream` types in the standard library.

I found that depending on how I read the data, the process could hang. After debugging I found that it depends on whether I use `read` or `read_to_end` to retrieve the data from the socket. Using `read` works fine, while using `read_to_end` makes the calling process to hang until I kill the other process (at which point the data is actually read). It almost seems like a problem with flushing the buffer, although the documentation doesn't mention anything of the sort.

This is a working example of the problem:

```
use std::env;
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixListener, UnixStream};
use std::thread;

fn handle_client(mut stream: UnixStream) {
    loop {
        let mut read = [0; 1028];
        match stream.read(&mut read) {
            Ok(n) => {
                if n == 0 {
                    // connection was closed
                    break;
                }
                let msg = String::from_utf8(read.to_vec()).unwrap();
                println!("SERVER: {} received from remote client.", msg);
                stream.write(&read[0..n]).unwrap();
            }
            Err(err) => {
                panic!(err);
            }
        }
    }
    println!("SERVER: Ending connection with client.");
}

fn start_server(address: String) {
    let listener = UnixListener::bind(&address).unwrap();

    // accept connections and process them, spawning a new thread for each one
    for connection in listener.incoming() {
        match connection {
            Ok(stream) => {
                /* connection succeeded */
                thread::spawn(|| handle_client(stream));
            }
            Err(err) => {
                /* connection failed */
                println!("Error connecting to client: {}", err);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn start_client(address: String, msg: String) {
    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(&address) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect! {}.", e);
            return;
        }
    };
    let request = msg.into_bytes();
    match socket.write_all(&request) {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => println!("Error writing to socket: {}", e),
    }

    // This variant works
    // let mut read = [0; 1028];
    // match socket.read(&mut read) {

    // This variant does not work.
    let mut read = Vec::with_capacity(1024); //Comment this to make it work
    match socket.read_to_end(&mut read) {
        // Comment this to make it work
        Ok(n) => {
            if n == 0 {
                // connection was closed
            }
            let msg = String::from_utf8(read.to_vec()).unwrap();
            println!("CLIENT: {} received from server.", msg);
        }
        Err(err) => {
            panic!(err);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    if args.len() > 2 {
        let operation_mode = args[1].clone();
        let address = args[2].clone();

        if operation_mode == "server" {
            start_server(address);
        } else {
            let msg = args[3].clone();
            start_client(address, msg);
        }
    } else {
        println!("not enough parameters");
    }
}
```

To reproduce the problem, run the server process like this: `rm /tmp/sock & RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run server /tmp/sock` and the client process afterwards like this: `cargo run client /tmp/sock hello_world`

The expected output when the problem reproduces is that the server process prints its output as expected: `SERVER: hello_world received from remote client.` but the client process prints nothing, until the server process is killed, at which point it prints its expected output: `CLIENT: hello_world received from server.`

To confirm this problem is localized to the `read_to_end` method, uncomment the lines that are marked as the working variant and comment the ones marked for the example to work.

What's the problem with this code? Am I using `read_to_end` wrong?

Comment: Hey @Shepmaster, thanks for the prompt response as always. I believe the questions are similar but different and the details are already in the question. The one you pointed me to has the same problem as me but with`read_to_string` which waits for EOF, while `read_to_end` would call read multiple times until it reads `Ok(0)`, so for an example like mine, it should read the entire message in the first read and then read `Ok(0)` and return. It seems to not be doing that last bit.

Comment: No, `read_to_end` and `read_to_string` have the exact same behavior — **both** read the entire stream until EOF; in fact `read_to_string` and `read_to_end` call the same core function internally. I've added the quote from the `read_to_end` documentation to the other answer to make it more obvious.

Comment: If that's the case, the documentation is wrong. Check the documentation for `read_to_end` here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end it points to the behaviour I mention.

Comment: The very first line of the documentation you just linked: *Read **all bytes until EOF** in this source, placing them into `buf`*. It will read available data into the buffer. When there's no data, *it will block,* waiting for more data to arrive. The only time it returns `Some(0)` is when the remote socket is closed (a.k.a. End Of File).

Comment: Shit, you are right, I don't know how I skimmed over that one very important line. In that case, you are right, this is the same as the TcpStream question and we can close this one as a duplicate. Thanks for your help!